# Failed to deploy Cloud Endpoint with OpenApi

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have `Python 2.7` `API` server using `Google Cloud Endpoints` framework. I follow the example from GitHub and code my service and configurations as explained in the documentation.

When I'm trying to deploy the endpoint using

```
gcloud endpoints services deploy echov1openapi.json
```

with my api json file, I get an error:

```
OperationErrorException: The operation with ID rollouts.MY_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com:5939cc3b-0b4a-4047-87d5-856ebdd44c0e resulted in a failure.

ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) The operation with ID rollouts.MY_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com:5939cc3b-0b4a-4047-87d5-856ebdd44c0e resulted in a failure.
```

I validate that all required APIs are enabled.

I tried to run the deployment command with `debug` option:

```
gcloud --verbosity=debug endpoints services deploy echov1openapi.json
```

without any other or additional error in the terminal

I've also checked the official troubleshooting page but this issue isn't described.

Even when I tried to deploy the official example from GitHub I got the same issue

This is the log from the `debug`:

```
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy] with arguments: [--verbosity: "debug", SERVICE_CONFIG_FILE:1: "[u'paymentsv1openapi.json']"]
Waiting for async operation operations/serviceConfigs.MY_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com:48e87eda-7009-47a1-9625-2ca1da025500 to complete...
Operation finished successfully. The following command can describe the Operation details:
 gcloud endpoints operations describe operations/serviceConfigs.MY_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com:48e87eda-7009-47a1-9625-2ca1da025500

Waiting for async operation operations/rollouts.MY_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com:5939cc3b-0b4a-4047-87d5-856ebdd44c0e to complete...
DEBUG: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) The operation with ID rollouts.MY_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com:5939cc3b-0b4a-4047-87d5-856ebdd44c0e resulted in a failure.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 985, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 795, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/endpoints/services/deploy.py", line 393, in Run
    services_util.ProcessOperationResult(rollout_operation, args.async)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/endpoints/services_util.py", line 481, in ProcessOperationResult
    op = GetProcessedOperationResult(result, is_async)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/endpoints/services_util.py", line 526, in GetProcessedOperationResult
    op_ref, GetClientInstance()))
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/endpoints/services_util.py", line 583, in WaitForOperation
    'The operation with ID {0} resulted in a failure.'.format(operation_id))
OperationErrorException: The operation with ID rollouts.MY_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com:5939cc3b-0b4a-4047-87d5-856ebdd44c0e resulted in a failure.
ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) The operation with ID rollouts.MY_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com:5939cc3b-0b4a-4047-87d5-856ebdd44c0e resulted in a failure.
```

Comment: I'm also seeing this for the first time today and wondering if it's due to the Google outage earlier. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=20077421

Comment: Also posted to usenet: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-endpoints/c2jzhf-8kd4

Comment: I suppose it is Google outage. I'm seeing this for the first time today, and I haven't changed anything from when it was working.

Comment: It seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved due to Google.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134361013

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-endpoints/c2jzhf-8kd4

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Cloud Endpoints Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-endpoints/c2jzhf-8kd4) Google knows about this problem and are actively working to fix it.